# Install distributed /usr/-like package hierarchy to the /usr/ directory

Tags: software-installation, file-copy

I have a software package that includes headers, libraries (including `lib64/`), a `bin/` directory, etc. that all need to be copied into the `/usr/` directory; for example:

```
./some-package-dist/
  bin/
  include/
  lib/
  lib64/
```

I have inspected these files to make sure that, if copied one by one from `./**/*` to `/usr/**/*`, they would work just fine - assuming the directory structure could also be created automatically, too (as in, the necessary directory hierarchy hasn't been created yet).

What is the easiest way to 'install' them to the `/usr/` directory without disrupting or corrupting any other existing files in the `/usr/` directory?

Comment: I would install the complete application in an app folder i.e. /usr/local/appname/

Comment: This is essentially what the Coreutils `install` program does - see `man install`

Comment: @RamanSailopal How does that solve anything?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm having trouble forming a proper command line for it - trying with an empty `/tmp/usr/` directory to test, nothing ever ends up in `/tmp/usr` but the `install` call returns 0. According to the man pages, something like `install -d -T ../usr ./` should work, but nothing seems to happen.